# Automorphism of a 3-connected graph which fixes rooting

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I was reading “[On the order of the group of a planar map](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980066800601#)” (Journal of Combinatorial Theory, v1 #3 (1966) pp.394–395) about automorphisms of 3-connected planar graphs.

A rooting of a plane graph is a triple $(v,e,f)$; some root vertex $v$, an incident edge $e$ of $v$, the root edge, and $f$ a face incident with $e$, the root face.

The article says that it is easy to see that an automorphism of $G$ a 3-connected planar graph which fixes some given rooting must be the identity.

I miss the argument why this is true?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article or a description of where you read it?

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980066800601#